# Angular $resource WebAPI FromBody Clarification

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angularjs-resource

I have my WebAPI controller defined like this

```
 [Route("~/api/v1/Employees/{id}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetEmployee([FromBody]int EmpID)
        {
            var emp = DB.Employees.FirstOrDefault(i => i.EmpID == EmpID) as Employee;
            return Request.CreateResponse<Employee>(HttpStatusCode.OK, emp);
        }
```

Here is the angular controller call to this method and angular service

controller:

```
$scope.Employee = EmpFactory.SingleEmployee.query({ id: ShareData.value }, { EmpID: 2 } , function (data) {
        emp = data;
    });
```

Service:

```
 SingleEmployee: $resource('/api/v1/Employees/:id', { id: '@id'}, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET'
                }            }
        )
```

**Note:** I have purposefully changed the parameter name to EmpID in my webAPI controller to understand how to call such methods from Angular..

**Question 1:**
It doesn't work.. From Fiddler, its very clear that EmpID is not getting passed while request

**Question 2:**
As per documentation, I need to pass the data/params to $resource method but in my case I m passing the parameter through the controller method without specifying anything directly in the $resource.. How does it work? Sorry if its a silly question

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supposed to tag is as [FromUri], which implies the variable is set In the URL.

Comment: I would like to know how the argument will be passed if it is [FromBody]